# Passing a classA struct into an outside function

Tags: c++

I have a class called aclass with a struct inside called aStuct. I'm looking to pass that into an outside function.

Note: The outside function is going to be defined in another .cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct {} aStruct;

class aclass
{
public:
    struct aStruct{
        int anInt;
    }structA;
};

void aFunction (aStruct *stuctA);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    aclass AClass;
    AClass.structA.anInt = 2;
    aFunction(&AClass.structA);
    std::cout << AClass.structA.anInt;
    return 0;
}

void aFunction (aStruct *stuctA)
{
    stuctA->anInt = 3;
}
```

Comment: `void Function (aclass::aStruct *stuctA)` BTW, nice names.

Comment: `typedef struct {} aStruct;` => what's the purpose of this? Do you realize that it declares a struct `::aStruct` which has no relation at all to `::aclass::aStruct`?

Comment: Alex, Cheers. I prefer small examples with very little information besides what's relevant to the question.

Jon, ah it was my attempt at solving the problem. Googling has told me I should forward declare my struct so my outside function knows what's going on. Atleast that's what I believe is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have two structures with the same name

```
typedef struct {} aStruct;

class aclass
{
public:
    struct aStruct{
        int anInt;
    }structA;
};
```

The first one is a global structure

```
typedef struct {} aStruct;
```

and the second one is a structure enclosed in a class definition

```
class aclass
{
public:
    struct aStruct{
        int anInt;
    }structA;
};
```

The parameter of function

```
void aFunction (aStruct *stuctA)
{
    stuctA->anInt = 3;
}
```

has type of the global structure. This function declaration is equivalent to

```
void aFunction ( ::aStruct *stuctA)
{
    stuctA->anInt = 3;
}
```

You have to define it as having type of the structure defined inside the class

```
void aFunction (aclass::aStruct *stuctA)
{
    stuctA->anInt = 3;
}
```